# Positivity of $\int_0^1 \sin^2(kx)f(x) dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I'm interested in proving restrictions on $f$ necessary for the integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^1 \sin^2 (kx) f(x) dx
\end{equation*}
to be positive for all $k > 0$. Obviously a nonnegative $f$ would suffice (provided it was positive on a set of nonzero measure). I'm wondering if there are less restrictive conditions that may be placed on $f$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: The limits of this integral are from zero to one? Not zero to, I don't know, $\pi$ or something?

Comment: If for any $z\in(0,1)$ you are able to approximate $\delta(z)$ with a linear combination (with non-negative coefficients) of functions of the form $\sin^2(kz)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos(2kz)\right)$, then $f\geq 0$ is necessary.

Comment: What regularity assumptions do we have on $f$? $f\in C^0(0,1)$ or $f\in L^2(0,1)$, by chance?

Comment: Actually my initial comment was completely misleading, but I am going to leave it for documentation purposes. I suggest to add the *harmonic-analysis* tag to the main question, since it seems pretty clear that Fourier series are the way to go, here.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer: the question is less trivial than I initially suspected.

It is practical to consider that $\sin^2(kx)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos(2kx)\right)$.
 Assuming $f\in L^2(0,1)$ we are allowed to write
$$ f(x) \stackrel{L^2(0,1)}{=} c_0 + \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n \cos(2\pi n x)+\sum_{n\geq 1} s_n \sin(2\pi n x) $$
where $c_0$ has to be non-negative as a consequence of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

By considering $k=\pi n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we get that each $c_n$ has to be $\leq 2c_0$.
This leaves enough room for plenty of somewhere-negative functions fulfilling the constraints for each $k\in \pi\mathbb{N}$, like

$$ \pi^2 x(1-x)+1-\frac{\pi^2}{6} = 1-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(2\pi n x)}{n^2} $$
which can be shown to fulfill the constraints for *any* $k>0$, ouch!

So my actual conjecture is that the claim holds iff the coefficients of the Fourier cosine series of $f(x)+f(-x)$ over $(0,1)$ fulfill some set of inequalities to be discovered. $f\geq 0$ is definitely *not* necessary.

Comment: Something simple like Cauchy-Schwarz can give a sufficient condition on $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^2)^{1/2}$ (seems to be something like $\leq 1.98 c_0$).