# An interpolation inequality for Fourier cosine series

Tags: inequality, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

This question arises as a follow-up to [MSE2874264](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874264/positivity-of-int-01-sin2kxfx-dx/2874305#2874305).
 Let us assume to have $f\in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ defined by
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} c_n \cos(nx) $$
where the coefficients $c_n$ are non-negative, decreasing to zero and such that $c_n=O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

> Is it true that for any $a\in(1,+\infty)$ the quantity
>   $ c_a \stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(ax)\,dx $ belongs to the interval $\left[c_{\lfloor a\rfloor+1},c_{\lfloor a \rfloor}\right]$? In such a case, what conditions on $f$ ensure that $c_a$ is a decreasing function?

We may easily check that
$$ c_a = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2a(-1)^n \sin(\pi a)}{\pi(a^2-n^2)}c_n $$
so if $a\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have that $c_a$ agrees with the coefficient $c_{\lfloor a\rfloor}$ from the Fourier cosine series of $f$.
 If that is not the case, an efficient strategy for bounding the previous series seems to invoke the Poisson summation formula and the fact that the Fourier transform of the $\operatorname{sinc}$ is well-known. Besides that I have not been able to produce sharp inequalities for $c_a$ in terms of $c_{\lfloor a\rfloor}$ and $c_{\lfloor a\rfloor+1}$ only.

Comment: It might be relevant to point out that by the Paley-Wiener theorem the Fourier transform of a compact-supported function is an entire function with order $1$, so the question is probably equivalent to: *if we know that an entire function is decreasing to zero over $\mathbb{N}^+$, what can be said about its behaviour over the half-lines contained in $\mathbb{R}^+$?*

Comment: Why is the $(-1)^n$ in your formula? When I take your formula, it's the same as $c_a = 2a\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tfrac{(-1)^n}{a+n}\operatorname{sinc}(a-n)c_n$. Hence, $c_m = 2m\tfrac{(-1)^m}{2m}c_m = (-1)^mc_m$...

Comment: @amsmath: you forgot the term $\frac{1}{a\color{red}{-}n}$ and $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(ax)\cos(nx)\,dx = \frac{2a\,\overbrace{\color{red}{\cos(n\pi)}}^{(-1)^n}\sin(\pi a)}{\pi(a^2-n^2)}.$$

Comment: I  didn't forget it. I just assumed that $\sin(\pi(a-n)) = \sin(\pi a)$. Too stupid. Thanx. So, your formula actually is $c_a = 2a\sum_{n=1}^\infty\tfrac{\operatorname{sinc}(a-n)}{a+n}c_n$.

Comment: As a counterexample, check out $f(x) = \cos(x)$. Then $c_a = \tfrac{2a}{a+1}\operatorname{sinc}(a-1)$, which oscillates around $0$.

Comment: For further possible calculations you might also want to work with the formula $c_a = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_{|n|}\operatorname{sinc}(a-n)$. Here and before, I used the definition $\operatorname{sinc}(x) = \tfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$.

Comment: @amsmath: so the answer to the first question is clearly negative, but the problem of bounding $c_a$ in terms of the adjacent $c_n$s still remains. Additionally the Fejer-Jackson inequality tells us something interesting about the partial sums of $\text{sinc}(a-n)$, so it looks like we might get something non-trivial by summation by parts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer relies in [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). As pointed out in the comments below the main question it is not granted that if $a\in(n,n+1)$ then $c_a\in(c_{n+1},c_n)$, but due to the following lemma, the given constraints ensure that $c_a$ cannot lie too far from such interval:

> For any $n\geq 4$ and any $x\in[0,n]$ we have that
>   $$ f_n(x)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\text{sinc}(\pi(x-k)) \in \left[\frac{2}{\pi}\text{Si}(2\pi),\frac{2}{\pi}\text{Si}(\pi)\right]\subset[0.902,1.179]$$
>   where $\text{sinc}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}1&\text{if }x=0\\ \frac{\sin x}{x}&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$ and $\text{Si}(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\text{sinc}(t)\,dt.$