# Integral of Hermite Polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, hermite-polynomials

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}, (1/\sqrt{2 \pi})\exp(-x^2/2))$ be such that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$.
We know that the (normalized) Hermite polynomials are a complete orthonormal basis for this space.  Therefore we let
\begin{equation}
f_n(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \langle f, H_i\rangle\ H_i(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i H_i(x),
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
c_i = \langle f, H_i \rangle = \int H_i(x) f(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp(-x^2/2)\ \mathrm{d} x = 
\int H_i(x) f(x)\ \phi(x) \mathrm{d} x,
\end{equation}
where $\phi(x) = (1/\sqrt{2 \pi}) \exp(-x^2/2)$.
Consider now the integral
\begin{equation}
d_i = \int H_i(x) f(x)\ \phi(x-\mu) \mathrm{d} x
\end{equation}
$d_i$ is the Hermite coefficient with respect to a translated Gaussian.

> Question:
>   Is there an upper bound for $|c_i - d_i|$? Ideally it would be something in 
>   the form $|c_i - d_i| \leq A c_i$.

My guess would be that 
there should exist some fixed constant $A$ such that 
\begin{equation}
|c_i - d_i| \leq A |c_i| \exp(\mu^2).
\end{equation}

I know that this question could be formulated only in terms of integrals
but I thought that providing more context could be helpful.

Any pointers to relevant literature are welcome.

Comment: With respect to another base of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, this is pretty reminiscent of this previous question of mine - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877625/an-interpolation-inequality-for-fourier-cosine-series

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer. We have

$$ c_i-d_i = \int H_i(x)f(x)\left(1-e^{\mu(x-\frac{\mu}{2})}\right)\phi(x)dx $$
hence by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ \left|c_i-d_i\right|\leq \sqrt{\left(e^{\mu^2}-1\right)\int H_i(x)^2f(x)^2\phi(x)\,dx}. $$
Since $f(x)\in[0,1]$ the inner integral is bounded by
$$ \int H_i(x)^2 \phi(x)\,dx = 1$$
and $\left|c_i-d_i\right|\leq e^{\mu^2/2}$, which maybe is enough for your purposes.
I am not sure on the route to follow for deriving an upper bound involving $|c_i|$, but [this past question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525094/proving-that-all-the-real-roots-of-hermite-polynomials-are-in-sqrt4n1-s/2525224#2525224) may be useful in the localization of the zeroes of $H_i(x)$.

Comment: Exactly this proof led me to believe that something in the form $|c_i - d_i| \leq \exp(\mu^2) |c_i|$ should exist.  Thanks though!! I will look in the other question you mentioned. I am not sure how to use the facts mentioned there for this problem though..